# How can I build a hashtable from a .csv where the first field in the csv row is the key and value is an array of the rest of the fields in that row

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I need to create a hash table from a list of email addresses in a csv file, where the first field of the row is a key and the rest of the fields in that row are a list of email addresses.
ex...

```
production,prod1@prod,prod2@prod
test,test1@test,test2@test
```

I'm trying...

```
$Hash = @{ }
foreach ($line in Get-Content "\mail.txt")
{
    $LineArray = $Line.Split(",")
    
    foreach ($field in $LineArray)
    {
        if ($field -ne $LineArray[0]) { $Hash[$LineArray[0]] += $field }
    }
}
```

I was hoping to get...

```
Name            Value
----            -----
production      prod1@prod,prod2@prod
test            test1@test,test2@test
```

What I'm getting is...

```
Name            Value
----            -----
production      prod1@prod.prod2@prod
test            test1@test.test2@test
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.Split` targeting the `count` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-8.0#system-string-split(system-char()-system-int32)):

```bash
$Hash = @{}
foreach ($line in Get-Content '\mail.txt') {
    $LineArray = $Line.Split(',', 2)
    $Hash[$LineArray[0]] = $LineArray[1]
}
```